# matrix display only first value of a field

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, report, reporting

i have the below matrix in report builder 3.0:

the field "Market Company Name" could have multiple values, however when i generate the report only the first value is displayed, while it should display each value on a row.
i tried to put it in the row group or column group it will display properly but the position of the field is not where i want it, i want it in this format.

can any one assist?? [image]

Answer (score 0):

If the data are displayed correctly when you use row grouping you can set the width of this column to 0. This way you keep the grouping but the column as such will not be visible.